# how to find the subfolder files in cmd?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I have tried the below code to copy the list of files in the myfile.txt file. The result files copied the current directory only but I want to copy all subfolder files which I mentioned in the file name on the text file. Is there a way to copy the files from subfolders?

myfile.txt contains the list of file names only.

```
 @echo off
 for /f "delims=" %%L in (G:\MyFile.txt) do copy "%%L" G:\
```

Comment: `for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("G:\MyFile.txt") do for /F "usebackq delims=" %%K in ('dir /B /S "%%L"') do copy "%%K" "G:\"`

Comment: May i know, where can i insert the src_folder? If i mentioned the path for each file, it refers only current path. I want to copy all the files from MyFile.txt and source path also mentioned another text file.

Comment: There are some possibilities; one would be replacing `dir /B /S "%%L"` by `dir /B /S "%SourcePath%\%%L"`

Comment: files not copied. below is the code.

for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("C:\Users\guest\Desktop\MyFile.txt") do for /F "usebackq delims=" %%K in ('dir /B /S "%C:\Users\guest\Desktop\Unit-testing%\%%L"') do copy "%%K" "C:\Users\guest\Desktop\"

Comment: MyFile.txt contain the below list of names. 
1.txt
2.txt

Comment: It must read `dir /B /S "C:\Users\guest\Desktop\Unit-testing\%%L"` (`%SourcePath%` was meant to be a variable rather than a literal path)